# How to make an object move and rotate the same amount as another obejct

Tags: unity, physics, rotation, movement, transformation

**INTRO:**

I am trying to make a camera move around in a fast moving, rotating in all axis, spaceship.... This person has achieved exactly what I need to achieve if that is a good reference for you (go to 5:30):

youtube.com/watch?v=eQt7TwCr6ao&ab_channel=TomWeiland

**MY PROGRESS:**

I have partially achieved this, by parenting the camera to the first person controller in a static ship and applying changes in transformations from the moving ship to the camera by using the following script. It works position-wise but rotation-wise the camera does not rotate around the ships origin when it rotates, or when I achieve this the camera doesnt move at all.

```
 public Transform TargetParent;

private Vector3 _localPosition;
private Vector3 _localEulerAngel;
private Vector3 _localScale;
private Vector3 _nextScale;

private Vector3 _lastPosition;
private Vector3 _lastEulerAngel;
private Vector3 _lastScale;


void Start()
{
    UpdateLastTranform();
    _localPosition = TargetParent.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position);
    _localEulerAngel = transform.eulerAngles - TargetParent.eulerAngles;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        _localScale[i] = transform.localScale[i] / TargetParent.localScale[i];
    }
    _nextScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}

void Update()
{
    _localPosition += _lastPosition - transform.position;
    _localEulerAngel += _lastEulerAngel - transform.eulerAngles;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        _nextScale[i] = _localScale[i] * (_lastScale[i] / transform.localScale[i]);
    }
    _localScale = _nextScale;

    transform.position = TargetParent.TransformPoint(_localPosition);
    transform.eulerAngles = TargetParent.eulerAngles + _localEulerAngel;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        _nextScale[i] = TargetParent.localScale[i] * _localScale[i];
    }
    transform.localScale = _nextScale;
    UpdateLastTranform();
}

private void UpdateLastTranform()
{
    _lastPosition = transform.position;
    _lastEulerAngel = transform.eulerAngles;
    _lastScale = transform.localScale;
}
```

**EDIT:**

So this is the scene setup:
[image]

**CONCLUSION:**

I need to make the camera be able to move and look around the rigidbody ship that can be rotating in all axis and moving at fast speeds in accordance with the static player controller

Comment: "I have tried using parent scripts that equal the first person controllers change in location and rotation" show us this code and explain how the output differs from what you expect.

Comment: ok I have showed the scripts in an edit in my post, I was also trying to detect a change in rotation and location on the player controller so i could then appply that change locally to the camera?

Comment: also when the parent script is enabled the camera doesn't follow the ship. Instead, it just stands still and moves and rotates with the player controller.

Comment: Also this is very important... This person has achieved exactly what I need to achieve if that is a good reference for you (go to 5:30): 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQt7TwCr6ao&ab_channel=TomWeiland

Comment: So you have two copies of the spaceship, one that moves and one that doesn't move? This is not clear from the way you wrote your post.

Comment: yes i do and I am trying to make it so that the camera rotates with the ship around its origin... Ill edit my questiion again to make it easier to understand, i am quite bad at explaining stuff like this lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two copies of your spaceship, one that is a moving Rigidbody and one that is stationary. You want the player to walk around the stationary ship, while the camera moves in the same way inside the Rigidbody ship.

Perhaps I'm not understanding something, but it seems like you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. It seems like all you would need is this:

```
//attach to camera that is a child of the moving spaceship
public class TrackedCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    //the first-person controller should be a child of the stationary spaceship
    [SerializeField] private Transform firstPersonController;

    void Update() {
        //give us the same position and rotation in our parent as the first person controller has in its parent
        transform.localPosition = firstPersonController.localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = firstPersonController.localRotation;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the scale, so I omitted that.

Comment: yes i am not using the scale, I edited my post so you can understand it better as well, I am testing out the script right now

Comment: The camera just teleports to the player controller...

Comment: @Object That means you didn't parent them correctly. The first person controller should be a child of the stationary spaceship, and the camera should be a child of the moving spaceship.

Comment: I am pretty sure i did that correctly?:
https://pasteboard.co/F0FatQQDENgM.png

Comment: @Object  In your screenshot you have an object named "PlayerShip" with children "MainShip", "collosionsd", "Capsule", and "Playercam". Is PlayerShip the actual ship mesh, or is MainShip the actual ship mesh? Same with the object named "stationary" - is that the ship mesh, or is "body" the ship mesh? The script probably won't work correctly if "MainShip" and "body" are the ship meshes.

Comment: @Object: Try this: drag two new copies of the ship mesh into the scene - not prefabs or anything like that, just the mesh. Without making any other changes, make the camera a child of one, and the first person controller a child of the other. Then start the scene.

Comment: I parented the whole player to the ship and it works... Now i just need to add artificial gravity so the player rigidbody falls towards the floor

Comment: It seems to work when I make the controller and camera part of the moving ship...

Comment: @Object If your question is solved, please remember to mark this as the correct answer to help future visitors.

Comment: I do remember marking it as answered and then leaving to do something, i guess i didnt click it. My bad